# How to get the count of unsaved associated records?

Tags: ruby, rails-activerecord

Given these ActiveRecord table definitions:

```
create_table :parents do |t|
end

create_table :children do |t|
  t.references :parent
end
```

And the corresponding models:

```
class Parent < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :children
end

class Child < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :parent 
end
```

When I create an unsaved record which has an unsaved association:

```
parent = Parent.new
parent.children << Child.new
```

And ask for the number of associated records:

```
parent.children.count
=> 0
```

Then the result is 0.  I expected 1.

I wish for the count I get to reflect both unsaved and saved associated records.  How can I get that count?

---

Versions:

- Rails 4.2.6
- Ruby 2.3.3

Comment: @spickermann Good find.  I did search before asking, but did not find that one.  That question specifies Rails 3.2.  I'm asking for Rails 4.2.  I have no reason to think that the answers would be different for the two versions.  Do you think we should edit the title of the other question to remove the version number, and then mark this as a duplicate?

Comment: I just had a look at the documentation of Rails 5.0 and the behavior is still the same. Therefore: Yes, I think it is a good idea to edit the other posts title and mark this as a duplicate.

Answer (score 8):

You need to use #size rather than #count.  As you (well, I)
discovered, #count ignores records in memory.  #size considers both
saved and unsaved records.

Here are the methods you can use to test for the existence or count of
associated records:

**count**

`count` only considers what in the database, ignoring anything in
memory.  This issues an SQL statement every time, ignoring any
caching.

**size**

To get the total number of saved and unsaved associated records, use
`size`.  This method differs from `length` in that it does not force
associated records to be loaded into memory.

**length**

To load all associated records into memory and then count all records, use `length`.  The total count of both saved and unsaved records will be returned.

**exists?**

To find out if there are any records on disk, ignoring the presence of
any in memory, use `exists?`.  This issues an SQL statement every time,
ignoring any caching.

## References

[a github comment by Carlos Antonio Dasilva](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/6978#issuecomment-8491439):

> - length with always load the objects and use Array#length
> - count will always do a SQL count
> - size will check whether the collection is loaded, and use it,
>     otherwise will do a count.
>
> size should give you the correct value in this case I think.